# Invalid value GLSL?

Tags: opengl, graphics, glsl

After letting my opengl program run for a while and viewing the scene from different angles I am getting an OpenGL "invalid value" error in my shader program. This is literally my program:

**Vertex**

```
#version 420
in vec4 Position;
uniform mat4 modelViewProjection;
void main()
{
    in vec4 Position;
    uniform mat4 modelViewProjection;
}
```

**Fragment**

```
#version 420
out vec4 fragment;
void main()
{
    fragment = vec4(1,0,0,1);
}
```

This error occurs right after the function call to tell OpenGL to use my shader program. What could the cause of this be? It happens regardless of the object I call it on. How can I get more information on what is going on? The error occurs almost randomly for a series of frames, but then works again after a while, fails again after a bit, ect.

If it helps, here is what my program linking looks like:

```
...
myShader = glCreateProgram();
CreateShader(myShader,GL_VERTEX_SHADER, "shaders/prog.vert");
CreateShader(myShader,GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, "shaders/prog.frag");
glLinkProgram(myShader);
PrintProgramLog(myShader);
...

void CreateShader(int prog, const GLenum type, const char* file)
{
    int shad = glCreateShader(type);
    char* source = ReadText(file);
    glShaderSource(shad,1,(const char**)&source,NULL);
    free(source);
    glCompileShader(shad);
    PrintShaderLog(shad,file);
    glAttachShader(prog,shad);
}
```

This is what I'm using to get the error:

```
void ErrCheck(const char* where)
{
    int err = glGetError();
    if (err) fprintf(stderr,"ERROR: %s [%s]\n",gluErrorString(err),where);
}
```

And here is what is being printed out at me:

```
ERROR: invalid value [drawThing]
```

It happens after I call to use the program:

```
glUseProgram(_knightShaders[0]);
ErrCheck("drawThing");
```

or glGetUniformLocation:

```
glGetUniformLocation(myShader, "modelViewProjection");
ErrCheck("drawThing2");
```

Comment: Can you post the line where the error occurs? Is it literally a call to `glUseProgram()`? I don't see any calls to `glGetError()`. Are you calling it after every OpenGL function call? Errors in OpenGL are sticky and if you don't get the error periodically, it will stick around until you do call `glGetError()`. This has thrown me off in the past. It seems like the error is coming from a particular function, but turns out it happened earlier and I just didn't check it.

Comment: Your vertex shader code doesn't look sensible. Looks like a Copy'n'Paste hickup to me.

Comment: Hmm, could you elaborate please datenwolf? What's wrong with it?

Comment: Where are you setting `gl_Position`? And why are you declaring the variables a second time within main?

Comment: If the error is indeed from `glUseProgram()` and not an earlier call, it means that your program id is invalid. If the same program worked earlier, the only logical explanation is that the program was deleted. I would set a breakpoint in the debugger where you call `glDeleteProgram()`, and make sure that you don't end up there. Accidentally deleting objects is much more common than you'd think...

Comment: UPDATE: After moving the `ErrCheck` function around, I found that it happens after `glGetUniformLocation`, not `glUseProgram()`

Comment: If that is *literally* your program, the VS should not compile. If by some miracle it does, then you have no active uniforms or attributes; any thing you try to query by name will therefore have no location. Do your shader/program info logs have anything to say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I fixed the problem. What I had above wasn't the whole truth, what I actually had was

```
myShader[0] = glCreateProgram();
```

myShader was an array of 4 GLuint(s), each int being a different shader program (although at this point they were all copies of the shader program I posted above). The problem was fixed when I stopped using an array and instead used:

```
GLuint myShader0;
GLuint myShader1;
GLuint myShader2;
GLuint myShader3;
```

Why this fixed the problem makes no sense to me, it's also pretty annyoing because rather than being able to index the shader mode I want, such as:

```
int mode = ... (code the determine what shader to use here)
glUseProgram(myShader[mode]);
```

I have to instead use conditionals:

```
int mode = ... (code the determine what shader to use here)
if (mode == 0) glUseProgram(myShader0);
else if (mode == 1) glUseProgram(myShader1);
else if (mode == 2) glUseProgram(myShader2);
else glUseProgram(myShader3);
```

If anyone of you know why this fixes the problem, I would very much appreciate the knowledge!

Comment: It is impossible to say what goes on in your original program if you do not show the relevant source code.

Comment: It doesn't make a difference if you have a array of 4 ids, or 4 individual variables. There must be something else going on.